# Time reversal symmetry for a tight binding Hamiltonian of spinless fermions with imaginary nearest neighbour hopping

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

How to prove that a tight binding Hamiltonian of spinless fermions with imaginary nearest neighbor hopping is invariant under time reversal?

$H=\sum_{j=1}^Lit\; c_j^\dagger c_{j+1}+h.c.$

where $t$ is real number.

And what is a minimal non-interacting Hamiltonian of spinless fermions without time reversal symmetry?